# Power Automate Flow multiple selection column

Tags: sharepoint-online, flow, power-automate

I am trying to write a flow from a SharePoint list where depending on a condition an email is sent to a group of users and lists the fields from the list in the email.

This seems straightforward when entering the values from most columns and works see image 1.
[image]

However there are some columns in the list that allow multiple selection values and as soon as I start trying to add the value from one of these columns eg contract reviewers it automatically starts adding a apply to each line see second image.
[image]

There are about 4 columns of this kind that I need to include the output in the email and it starts adding the apply to each line so that instead of getting one email I get many. Is there any way that I can insert something so that it stops trying to do this but allows me to display those values in one email?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the email adresses with a "Select and Join" pattern.

So before the email action you first insert a "Select" action. In the From field you select the base object of the person field (the other will have an appendix to the field name like Claims, Email etc). In the Map field you first press the little "map" icon so that the field is just one single line. In that field you pick the Person field with the Email appendix. This way you select all the emails from the person field without a loop.

Next you insert a "Join" action. In the From field you select the output of the Select action. In the Join with field you put an ";". This way every email adress will be joined with a ";" between them.

The output of the Join action you can put into the "To" field in the Outlook send email action.

You can do this pattern for any multivalue field :)

[image]